# Inhibit modal window from closing on background click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, and I am creating a modal with a shaded background. I want the modal to stay up until I click close, and when someone clicks the background it **will not** close.

I can't find a solution. I know how to do with a backdrop, but then there is no background.

Comment: thanks for the edit, and sorry for the mistakes, I'm just in a rush for solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modal, there is a data attribute called backdrop. You can set it to true or false:

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

You can also specify it as static if you want the backdrop but it should not close on clicking.

Another hack is to disable the backdrop and have your own backdrop with the following properties so that the modal doesn't close on clicking.
CSS for the backdrop:

```
{
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000000;
opacity:0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myModal').modal({
  backdrop: 'static',
  show: false
})

// by default backdrop: true so just set it to static.
```

Comment: The backdrop: 'static' is definitely better answer for the desired behavior than the other answer here.